# Finding the middle ten characters of a sentence + printing more text on each line

Tags: java

So pretty much, I have this piece of code. It's intended to take a sentence, and print each word on its own line. It's also supposed to find the middle ten characters of a sentence.

My problem is that I'm unsure how to make it so that I actually get the middle ten characters of a sentence. Currently in the code, it's written so that it finds the last two digits. Also, I would like to make it so that instead of having only the words print out on each line, I'd like it to say 
"first word: this" "second word: is" and so forth. Still, each on a separate line. Any help or guidance would be very appreciated, thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sentence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a sentence with 5+ words: ");
        String sentence = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println();

        int space = sentence.indexOf(" ");
        sentence = sentence.substring(0, space) + "\n" + sentence.substring(space + 1);
        System.out.println(sentence.replaceAll("\\s+", "\n"));

        String substring = sentence.length() > 10 ? sentence.substring(sentence.length() / 2) : sentence;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("MIDDLE 10 CHARACTERS: " + substring);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at String.split(...). Then iterating through the resulting array.
For the substring: Check if the string is long enough like you did. Then get the middle like you did, lets call it "m". Then use substring with a starting index (=m-5) and a length attribute (=10) (notice that substringt() is overloaded and comes in different versions)

Comment: This is two separate questions.  For the first part, it's easiest just to use the `replace` method to swap spaces for newlines.  For the second part, you've got the right idea, but your arithmetic is off.  See if you can work out the correct values to pass to `substring`, to get the middle ten characters.  Note that you'll need to do subtraction as well as division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String sentence = "He went to Accra today";
    while((sentence.length() < 10) || (sentence.length() > 10)){
        sentence = sentence.substring(1);
        sentence = sentence.substring(0,sentence.length()-1);
    }
    System.out.println("Middle 10 is \""+sentence+"\"");
```

Output:

> Middle 10 is "t to Accra"